# Power BI - while creating a new measure, how do I drop down onto a new row?

Tags: powerbi, measure

I am trying to learn Power BI and while watching a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBddNp_25YY the host is showing how to create a measure. When you select "New measure" the number "1 measure =" appears automatically in the bar. He then changes this to read "1 sales across prior years = VAR MaxMonth = [MaxMonth]" with MaxMonth being a measure already created.

However, then in order to see whether that part of the code is working as desired, 10.41 into the attached video clip on youtube, he manages to get the bar to drop down to a new row which says "2" and he types in RETURN MaxMonth to see if the value he expects gets returned.

I cannot get the bar to drop down to a new row. If I select the return key on my computer it thinks I am finished the measure , if I select the tab key it just moves forward a few spaces. I am not able to do what he is doing and see whether the calculaiton is working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Shift + Enter** to move to the next line.